# passing extra parameter to event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below i have `util.doSomething()` method which takes json object as parameter. When util is done doing something it calls `onDone` event handler by passing a `response` as parameter.

I wanted to know in the code below if it is possible to pass `id` to `update` event handler?

```
$(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    util.doSomething({
          property1: "SomeValue1",
          property2: "SomeValue2",
          onDone: update //ho do i pass id to update event handler?
      })
  })

   function update(response,id)
   {
      //update
   }
})
```

I know i can get hold of id using inline event handler. like

```
  $("#btn").click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');

    util.doSomething({
          property1: "SomeValue1",
          property2: "SomeValue2",
          onDone: function(response){
               // now i can use id here
         }
      })
  })
```

Comment: Without knowing what your `doSomething` is doing, it isn't really possible to know what can be done. You could attach the id to the object that is calling `onDone`. Usually events are run with `this` set to the calling object or element.

Comment: so whats wrong using inline function? otherwise you need to modify `doSomething` to take additional `id` param and pass that to `onDone`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .bind method and the arguments object inside the function to access extra parameters you want to pass in

```
$(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    util.doSomething({
          property1: "SomeValue1",
          property2: "SomeValue2",
          onDone: update.bind(this, id)
      })
  })

   function update()
   {
       console.log(arguments); // inside arguments you should see all your parameters
       // arguments[0] your id
       // arguments[1] your response
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `onDone` to `update`, you can set it to a function that calls `update` with the arguments you want.

```
util.doSomething({
    property1: "SomeValue1",
    property2: "SomeValue2",
    onDone: function(response) {
      return update(response, id);
    }
})
```